# Overheating and coolant tank problems

Tags: coolant-reservoir

I got my radiator replaced two day ago on the second day my truck started acting weird. Suddenly my coolant tank started bubbling and it was loud causing my truck to over heat. What can be the problem

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of your truck?

Comment: Please say why you got your radiator replaced. Use the EDIT link below your question to add additional details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.